# Foreign-Key References to the Same Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

I have the below model:

```
class Client
{        
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }         
    public Nullable<DateTime> date_naissance { get; set; }
    public Sex? Sexe { get; set; }
    public Client Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I used code first to generate my table. When I tried to save the records using the code below, I wasn't able to determine how to populate the `Parent` field. A `Client` can be a parent of other `Client`s.

```
Client client = new Client();

client.Id = int.Parse(item.ID);
client.Nom = item.Nom;
client.Prenom = item.Prenom;
client.date_naissance = DateTime.Parse(item.DateNaissance);
client.Sexe = (Sex)Enum.Parse(typeof(Sex), item.Sexe);

int parent;
bool par = int.TryParse(item.Parent, out parent);

// this does not work:                       
if (par)
    client.Parent.Id = parent;

db.clients.Add(client);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If by "this does not work" you mean you get a NullReferenceException, that's because `client.Parent` is `null`. You need to assign a new instance to that property and then assign the `Id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the navigation properties (i.e. Parent) virtual and don't forget to initialize them. So first you have to change your class property to:

```
public virtual Client Parent { get; set; }
```

and then in the code:

```
client.Parent = new Parent();
client.Parent.Id = parentId;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the parent `Client` instance is not already created, you will need to create a new one. You can always create a new `Client` instance and assign it the parent's Id, but the instance assigned will lack all of the other information about the parent. An example of this is below.

```
client.Parent = new Client() { Id = parentId };
```

Ideally, you will look up the parent from the context and assign it to the client:

```
var parent = context.Clients.Find(parentId);
if (parent != null)
{
    client.Parent = parent;
}
else
{
    // Handle an invalid ID
}
```

Additionally, I would suggest changing the `Parent` property to a virtual property:

```
public virtual Client Parent { get; set; }
```

This will allow you to take advantage of two useful features of the Entity Framework: lazy loading and automatic change tracking. Entities or collections of entities referenced by navigation properties specified with the `virtual` keyword will only be loaded the first time they are used. With the `virtual` keyword, accessing the `Parent` property the first time will load the `Parent` entity for that `Client` and return it. Without the `virtual` keyword, the `Parent` property will return `null` unless you explicitly load and assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to pass the whole Client structure as the parent, you may pass only the integer ID to refer to the parent.

Answer (score -1):

you must create an instance of the parent. or you can't set it.

```
class Client
{                
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Client Parent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Client"/> class.
    /// 
    /// WITH PARENT
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="parent">The parent.</param>
    public Client(int id, Client parent)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Parent = parent;                    
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Client"/> class.
    /// 
    /// WITHOUT PARENT
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    public Client(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Client client = new Client(1);

        Client clientWithParent = new Client(2, client);

        Console.Write("parent id :" + clientWithParent.Parent.Id);
}
```